# How to check Cordova version in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2013

Where I find the version of cordova on which a project is running in Visual Studio ?. There is no mention of it in 'config.xml'.

Comment: In VS 2015 with Tools for Apache Cordova you've got a taco.json in the root of every TACO-project. It looks something like this `{
 "cordova-cli": "6.0.0"
}`. Maybe there is something similar in VS 2013...

Comment: I did check expecting to find something similar to how its in VS2015 but unfortunately there isn't any.

Comment: Hmm then you could try to use the command line like `cordova -v`. If Cordova isn't installed globally it might be somewhere in C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules depending on your node.js installation.

Comment: @August If you have cordova CLI installed, typing 'cordova -version' in command prompt should get you the version

Answer (score 0):

Open the Config.xml in view designer(default double click) and under Platforms you can select what version of CLI the project will run from, or just check what version it is currently running under.

Comment: This option isn't present in VS2013. I think it's there in VS2015.

Comment: @August my bad I missed the VS2013 Tag sorry. It is there in VS2015 as I am using it. I was on 2013 early last year you could view the config.xml in view designer but I can not confirm if the tab is there for the CLI version as this was a pretty new addition and might not have been pushed backwards to 2013. Just checked back on any old documentation and 3.4 the XML view designer became available but can not see at what point the CLI Tab became available sorry.